# Deploying to Azure Web App from Travis CI

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, travis-ci

I am trying to deploy a solution from Travis to Azure Web App. I've followed [this](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/real-life-code/2015/09/30/travis-azure.html) post and created local git repository deployment in Azure, with deployment credentials.

I have this in my .travis.yml

```
deploy:
 provider: azure_web_apps
 skip_cleanup: true
 verbose: true
```

Which gives this error

> error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master
>   The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
>   begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.

I have dug around, and found that I need to call

```
git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

in order to initialise the repository, but I've no idea where to put this in the .travis.yml

I could write the whole git push part myself, but that seems to negate the purpose of the Travis Azure functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to answer here, but I imagine a solution would be to add the following to `.travis.yml`:

```
before_deploy: "git push origin master:refs/heads/master"
```